# Count in Query 400 not passing correctly

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I Have a table that has order data like this: Table Order_Detail and Item_Master are joined by Item#
We want to report on order number, 
Order_Detail table:

```
Order#     Item#              

1234       IPhone6 
1234       IPhone5
1234       Battery

join Item_Master:

Item#            Item_type    Desc

IPhone6          Phone        Smartphone
IPhone5          Phone        Smartphone
```

Now we only want order numbers, that have only one Item-Type = Phone. We are only interested in types Phone. I tried using Query/400 and doing a count on order# which = Phone, and then taking only the counts = 1. But this does bring in some orders that have more than one phone type = Phone, in our example here we would not want this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query will return ordernums where the only ordered item type is 'phone'

```
select ordernum
from order_detail od
join item_master im on im.itemnum = od.itemnum
group by ordernum
having count(case when im.item_type <> 'Phone' then 1 end) = 0
and count(*) = 1
```

if you want to allow multiple 'phone' orders you can remove `and count(*) = 1`

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little confusing.  Are you looking to get a count of order numbers where `Item_Type = 'Phone'`?  If so the follwoing should work for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNum) AS OrderNumCount
FROM Order_Detail o
INNER JOIN Item_Master i ON o.ItemNum = o.ItemNum
WHERE Item_type = 'Phone'
```

Or are you after only the orders that have only one record from the item table linked.  If so then you may want:

```
SELECT o.OrderNum
FROM Order_Detail o
INNER JOIN Item_Master i ON o.ItemNum = o.ItemNum
WHERE Item_type = 'Phone'
GROUP BY o.OrderNum
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: yes but we only want to pass further if the count = 1 that is, only one row has the item_type = Phone

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
SELECT o.OrderNum 
FROM 
  Order_Detail o 
INNER JOIN 
  Item_Master m
On o.ItemNum = m.ItemNum
WHERE m.Item_Type = 'Phone'
GROUP BY o.OrderNum
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```